# Splitting a triangle to make two equal halves, find the length of the new line

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Could someone please explain to me how I would find this out?

I have a triangle and I need to find the length of the line that would split it down the middle so that the areas were even.

A = 105 degrees

B = 42 degrees

C = 33 degrees

AB = 3.2

AC = 3.9

BC = 5.7

The line needs to be draw across the triangle splitting angle A (the 105 degrees angle).

The total area of the triangle is $6.075km^2$ , so the two halves have to be equal in area.

Can anyone help me out here? Thank you!

Comment: A truncation error occurs in your data set. Assuming that all the angles, plus AB = 3.2 and BC = 5.7 are all correct, then AC = .. by cosine law .. = 3.9(522). There are other combinations too. Should the correct combination be used, it is possible to get an answer matching that from the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line has to be drawn just through the midpoint of $BC$.

A median splits a triangle in two triangles having the same base and the same height, hence equal areas.

To find the length of a median you can use the formula:
$$ m_a^2 = \frac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{4},$$
giving in your case:
$$ m_a = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\cdot 3.9^2+2\cdot 3.2^2-5.7^2}=2.145\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you - I have done so using the Apollonius Theorem, and am coming up with the answer 2.15km. My book has the answer of 1.19km. I am completely stuck with how they got there!?

Comment: @Dani: I got the same answer by using the Stewart's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) hence I think we can assume the book is wrong.

Comment: I don't believe any line segment of length 1.19(km) can even reach from any vertex of the triangle to its opposite edge, so it's hard to understand where that number could come from.

Comment: Ok... so it is likely that they have supplied me with the wrong answer? I got the same answer as you did. Thanks for your help

Comment: @StevenStadnicki is clearly right, the shortest height has length $\frac{2\cdot6.075}{5.7}=2.13\ldots$.

Comment: Thank you. Can I just check,I had to find the length of side BC, which I found to be 5.7km. This allowed me to find the correct area. Theres no way I could have miscalculated that side is there? (the other two side lengths were given, as well as all mentioned angles).

Comment: The initial data were the area and the angles or just the lengths of the sides?

Comment: @Dani I haven't done a close calculation (with law of sines or law of cosines), but it sounds about right - 105 degrees isn't too far off from 90, and a 45-45-90 triangle with one leg 3.9km would have its 'long edge' on the order of 5.5km, so it's certainly in the ballpark.

Comment: The initial data were the sides 3.2 and 3.9 (AB and AC), plus all three angles. I calculated side BC and the area - the area was correct according to my book. Its just this last bit that I think they've provided the wrong answer. I used the sine rule to calculate side BC.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help - I think the answer provided by the book must be wrong! I'e double checked my working for side BC and can't fault it. Thank you!